# How Parsing string between [STX] and [ETX] using C# - Split/Append output using Regex or String Functions

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, string

**Language = C#.NET**

**Anything that is between [STX] and [ETX] must be accepted rest of the things must be rejected.**

> ```
> string startparam = "[STX]";
> string endparam = "[ETX]";
>
> String str1 = "[STX]some string 1[ETX]"; //Option 1
> String str2 = "sajksajsk [STX]some string 2 [ETX] saksla"; //Option 2
> String str3 = "[ETX] dksldkls [STX]some string 3 [ETX]ds ds"; //Option 3
> String str4 = "dksldkls [STX]some string 4.1[ETX]ds ds [STX] some string 4.2[ETX] jdskjd"; //Option 4
>
> /* the various strings can be appended and converted to a single 
>    string using string builder or treat them as different strings*/
>
> ProcessString (string str , string startparam , string endparam)
> {
>    //What To Write here using RegEX or String Functions in c#
>
> }
>
> /* The output after passing these to a ProcessString () */     
> /* Append Output To a TextBox or Append it to a String using For Loop.*/
>
> /* Output Required */
>
> some string 1 
> some string 2
> some string 3
> some string 4.1 
> some string 4.2
> ```

=============================================================================

## EDIT 2

```
Language = C#

string str = "
[STX]some string 1[ETX]
sajksajsk [STX]some string 2 [ETX] saksla
[ETX] dksldkls [STX]some string 3 [ETX]ds ds
dksldk[STX]ls [STX]some st[ETX]ring 4.1[ETX]ds ds [STX]some string 4.2[ETX] jdskjd";
```

How can i get the same output if the string array is one single string

```
/* output */
some string 1 
some string 2
some string 3
some string 4.1 
some string 4.2


/*case 1*/ 
the above string can be "[STX] djkdsj [STX]dskd1[ETX] dsnds[ETX]" 
the output should be just "dskd1"

/*case 2*/ 
the above string can be "[STX] djkdsj [STX]dskd1[ETX] ddd" 
the output should be just "dskd1"

/*case 3*/ 
the above string can be " kdsj [STX]dskd1[ETX] dsnds[ETX]" 
the output should be just "dskd1"

/*case 4*/ 
the above string can be "[STX] djk[STX]dsj [STX]dskd2[ETX] ddd" 
the output should be just "dskd2"

The real problem comes when [STX] followed by [STX] i want to consider the newer [STX] and start string processing from the newer [STX] occurance. Eg. Case 2 above
```

=============================================================================

## EDIT 3 : New Request

Language = C#

If i want the data between [STX] and [STX] also can that also be done.

New RegEx which will extract data between
1. [STX] some Data [STX]
2. [STX] some Data [ETX]

Eg.

```
/* the above string can be */
"[STX] djk[STX]dsj [STX]dskd2[ETX] ddd" 
/* the output should be just */
djk
dsj
dskd2
```

As [STX] means a transmission has been started so i want to extract data between STX as well.

Comment: Having two users http://stackoverflow.com/users/459859/sanket-s and http://stackoverflow.com/users/460305/sanket-s -- is planned?

Comment: Please put EDIT 3: New Request into a new question and delete it from here.

Comment: I am looking out for a way to handle date coming from serial port after sending stx-etx command. Seems like you have gone beyond that part. It would be great if you could give some ideas about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=\[STX\])(?:(?!\[STX\]).)*?(?=\[ETX\])
```

matches any text (except newlines) between `[STX]` and `[ETX]`:

```
(?<=\[STX\])  # Are we right after [STX]? If so,...
(?:           # match 0 or more of the following:
 (?!\[STX\])  # (as long as it's not possible to match [STX] here)
 .            # exactly one character
 )*?          # repeat as needed until...
(?=\[ETX\])   # there is a [ETX] ahead.
```

This will always match `somestring` in each of the following:

```
blah blah [STX]somestring[ETX] blah blah
[STX]somestring[ETX] blah [STX]somestring[ETX] (hey, two matches here!)
[STX] not this! [STX]somestring[ETX] not this either! [ETX]
blah [ETX] [STX]somestring[ETX] [STX] bla bla
```

A full reference on positive/negative lookbehind and lookahead assertions (three of which are used in this regex) can be found in Jan Goyvaerts' excellent regular expression tutorial at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Comment: I am just starting with RegEx its very difficult to understand it can you further simplify how this works , some web link which would be helpful in understanding RegEx easily.

Comment: what does <= in (?<=\\[STX\\]) mean in regex terms

Comment: `(?<=XXX)` is a positive [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html "Lookaround"). It means "look backwards from the current position and see if there is a `XXX` there".

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
string[] sepValues = input.Split(new char[] {'\u0002', '\u0003'},
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[STX\](.*?)\[ETX\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And then just pick out the group to get the string between the tags

Comment: This will fail in strings like `[STX] not this [STX] THIS! [ETX]`.

Comment: @Tim it depends on what you want... If you want the things between the outer or the inner.

Comment: He said he wants the inner ones. However, he wrote this in an answer instead of editing his question...

Comment: @Tim Didn't see that (it was actually posted after my answer)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** to fit your updated requirements you should use this pattern that takes advantage of look-arounds to skip all STX groups except the last one that has an ETX after it:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\[STX])?.*\[STX]\s*(.+?)\s*\[ETX].*?";
```

Here's a complete example:

```
string input = @"[STX]some string 1[ETX]
sajksajsk [STX]some string 2 [ETX] saksla
[ETX] dksldkls [STX]some string 3 [ETX]ds ds
dksldkls [STX]some string 4.1[ETX]ds ds [STX] some string 4.2[ETX] jdskjd
[STX] djkdsj [STX]dskd1[ETX] dsnds[ETX]
[STX] djkdsj [STX]dskd1[ETX] ddd
kdsj [STX]dskd1[ETX] dsnds[ETX] 
[STX] djk[STX]dsj [STX]dskd2[ETX] ddd";

string pattern = @"(?<=\[STX])?.*\[STX]\s*(.+?)\s*\[ETX].*?";

foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    // result will be in first group
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

I also added the `\s*` between the grouping to eliminate extra whitespace. By doing so you no longer need to use `Trim()` as I suggested in my earlier response below.

---

**PREVIOUS RESPONSE**

This pattern should fit: `"\[STX](.+?)\[ETX]"`

Notice that the opening bracket, `[`, must be escaped to prevent it from being interpreted as a character class in regex. The closing bracket, `]` need not be escaped. The `(.+?)` is a capturing group (due to the parentheses) and matches at least one character in a non-greedy fashion (via the `?`). By being non-greedy it prevents the regex engine from greedily matching multiple occurrences and content till the last "[ETX]" occurrence. Remove the `?` and you'll see what I mean in your `str4` example. Since your last example has multiple occurrences you can use the [Matches method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx).

```
string[] inputs =
{
    "[STX]some string 1[ETX]",
    "sajksajsk [STX]some string 2 [ETX] saksla",
    "[ETX] dksldkls [STX]some string 3 [ETX]ds ds",
    "dksldkls [STX]some string 4.1[ETX]ds ds [STX] some string 4.2[ETX] jdskjd"
};

string pattern = @"\[STX](.+?)\[ETX]";

foreach (string input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input: " + input);
    foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
    {
        // result will be in first group
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    }

      Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You might consider using a `Trim()` to trim any excess spaces (`m.Groups[1].Value.Trim()`). It's possible to achieve in the pattern but complicates it unnecessarily. Use the overload that accepts `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` if you need to ignore the case of the "STX" and "ETX" text (if they aren't always in uppercase form).